# multiple Inheritance design issue

Tags: php, inheritance, model-view-controller

I don't know how i can best solve this problem. 
I have a BaseBackEndController that implements basic functionality.

```
abstract class BaseBackEndController{
     public function getOptionalValues(){}

     protected function view($model = null, $viewName = null){}

     protected function redirectToAction($action, $controller = null){}

     public function getOptionalValues(){}

     protected function addOptionalValue($key,$value){}
}
```

I wanted to add database functionality with a UnitofWork so i made a UnitOfWorkBackEndController that uses a implementation of a UnitOfWork to handle database functionality.

```
abstract class UoWBackEndController extends BaseBackEndController{
     function __construct(IUnitOfWork $uow){}

     protected function getSessionUser(){}

     private function retrieveUserFromSession(){}

}
```

Then i also wanted to get access to the user that is logged in so i wanted some kind of way to access this but then i was already kinda suspicious when i made a class called UoWWithUserSessionBackEndController.

Now if i want to acces the session i need to give a UoW implementation and thats not what i want. I don't really know how to solve this so that it makes sense.

```
abstract class UoWWithUserSessionBackEndController extends UoWBackEndController{
    function __construct(IUnitOfWork $uow) {
        parent::__construct($uow);

        // retrieve user from session and set it in the field
        $this->_userInSession = $this->retrieveUserFromSession();
     }
     protected function getSessionUser(){}
     private function retrieveUserFromSession(){}
}
```

or

```
abstract class UoWWithUserSessionBackEndController extends UoWBackEndController{
    function __construct(IUnitOfWork $uow, ISessionHelper $sessionHelper) {
        parent::__construct($uow);

        // retrieve user from session and set it in the field
        $this->_sessionHelper =  $sessionHelper;
     }
     protected function getSessionHelper(){}
}
```